# Match all characters except one

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a test string with pattern

```
{something1=any_character} any_character {something2=any_character}
```

I wanted to match the first bracketed sequence and in next iteration I wanted to match the next. So I am using `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

The regex I have is `\{(\w)*something1.*(?!=).*(?!\})` but the problem is that it match the complete string rather then just the first one. I want to break the first search at first `}` and then find next `}`.

Comment: It's probably not the answer to your question, but sometimes (and in this particular example I'd do it) it's more simple and easy just to split a string using "}" and "{" as delimiters, and analyse substrings.

Comment: yes, but i feel its much easier to match and replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the wildcard lazy:

```
\\{(\\w)*?something1.*?(?!=).*?\\}
```

Comment: Did I get the question wrong?. Why can't he just capture values in braces and find groups using `matcher.find()`?

Comment: @TheLostMind: You're right, I've just fixed OP's regex.

Comment: how would a replaceFirst function works with this matcher.group()?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Pattern` and `Matcher`, then only capture groups like this :

`(\\{\\w+=\\w+\\})` and use a `while()` loop with `matcher.find()`

Comment: I have something1 and something2. I just want to match something1 not the other one. And there can be multiple something1

Comment: @Ata - then use `something1` instead of first `\\w+` in my regex . COuld you show us your *exact input and output*?

Comment: @Ata - BTW if you use `()` you are capturing values not just macthing them :)